# C# Custom GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, search, gridview

I'm not really proficient in `asp.net`. I Have a asp based web application and I want to create a custom `GridView` in order to use it whenever I have a search box and reduce redundancy in my code.

I want to have this `GridView` below my `textbox` and on text changing the `GridView` shows mostly searched results and a "More" button for advance search which will open a new page. Can anybody help me how can I start?

Thanks.

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1597504.aspx?Filtering+GridView+ ?

Comment: @G_S thanks for your reply. but my problem is not filtering and searching. The problem is caching most searched results and scroll on them. and Implementing the show more button for advance search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a small example of how you could achieve this. First add the necessary items needed to do a search to the aspx page. Note that the buttons have an `OnCommand` so that you can send a `CommandName` along with them.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="SearchField" runat="server" MaxLength="50"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"
    ErrorMessage="A search term is required" ValidationGroup="Search" 
    ControlToValidate="SearchField">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button ID="SearchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" 
    OnCommand="DoSearch_Command" CommandName="Search" ValidationGroup="Search" />

<asp:GridView ID="SearchResultsGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="MoreButton" runat="server" Text="More" 
    OnCommand="DoSearch_Command" CommandName="More"/>
```

Now in the code behind you process the button clicks of `Search` and `More`. I created some dummy data with a `List`, but you need to replace that with the correct data source that holds your search results (List, DataTable etc).

```
protected void DoSearch_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    //create a new item to hold search results, in this case a list
    List<string> searchResults = new List<string>();

    //the text from the textbox that contains the search word
    string searchTerm = SearchField.Text.Trim();

    //hide the 'more' button
    MoreButton.Visible = false;

    //add some dummy data for testing
    for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
    {
        searchResults.Add("Search result " + i);
    }

    //if the results are more than 10 and the click is not from the 'more' button take 10 items
    if (searchResults.Count > 10 && e.CommandName == "Search")
    {
        searchResults = searchResults.Take(10).ToList();

        //show the more button
        MoreButton.Visible = true;
    }

    //show results in gridview
    SearchResultsGridView.DataSource = searchResults;
    SearchResultsGridView.DataBind();
}
```